# How to pass session information to a subdirectory in php

Tags: php, session, subdirectory

I'm creating a simple website in PHP that users can log into.

All pages in the root directory work fine, but when I try and start a session on a web page in a subdirectory it doesn't read it

This is what I have at the start of the web pages in the subdirectory, which as I say works fine for every page in the root directory -

```
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location: http://www.four-corners.org.uk/welcome.php");
```

several people seem to have the same problem but I've not found a solution yet

**Edit -**

Below is the code I've used to define 'myusername' and register it in the session

```
// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=md5($_POST['mypassword']);

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
```

Comment: Do you get anything if you do `var_dump($_SESSION)`?

Comment: thanks @Nalum, I wasn't sure where to put var_dump($_SESSION) but wherever I seemed to place it I came up with the error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in D:\four-corners.org.uk\wwwroot\destination\australia.php on line 3

Comment: can you show the code that you have on line 3 of `australia.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session_is_registered()` is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

The equivalent "modern" code would be

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION[myusername])) {
  ...
}
```

Note that I've duplicated your 'myusername' exactly. Without a `$` sign in front of it, it's treated as a constant. If you've not used `define()` to set that constant, it'll evaluate to a null and get cast to an empty string before going into session_is_registered. Unless your session has a value with an empty string as a key, you'll get redirect every time.

Comment: And you've just changed my answer completely. Read the paragraph after the code snippet.

Comment: You mean to say `myusername` is defined as constant separately as `defined('myusername','something')`

Comment: That's why I wrote the paragraph. OP's code snippet doesn't have the quotes, so I duplicated that, and explained why it might be wrong.

Comment: thank you @shakti and @mark for taking the time to answer. I've updated the code so that it's no longer deprecated and it all still works fine with web pages in the root directory.  The session is still not being picked up by web pages in sub-directories however. I've not used define() anywhere in the code, I'll add the code where it's defined to the question if that might make it easier?

Comment: Have you checked if the session cookie is being sent to the pages in those subdirs? Use Firebug or HTTPFox to examine the headers in the requests as they go back and forth.

Comment: @Chris : `session_register` is also deprecated http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php

Comment: Thanks for the info Shakti - have gone through my code and hopefully updated any deprecated code.  I also used Firebug to check, Mark and it turns out the session is being sent to the page in a sub-directory.  But I'm using a javascript auto-complete box to direct users to the page and somewhere in that process it loses the session - I still haven't figured out why, but that's a whole different problem I need to look into. Thank you both for your help with this!